# determining m,n for line be part of plane

Tags: linear-algebra

i want to determine m,n for line be part of a plane.

The line (x,y, z) = (n, 2, 0) + t(2, m, m) 
The plane:: π : x − 3y + z = 1

so, i tried this way:
i have

```
x = n+2t
y = 2+mt
z = mt
```

So, lets substitute on pi.

```
(n+2t) - 3(2+mt)+mt = 1
n+2t-2mt = 7
```

so, i dont know what can i do to find m,n using this things.

Thanks.

Comment: The line will be part of the plane iff two points of it are in the plane. So from what you have, put $t=0$ and then $t=1$ to get equations on $m,n$ to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Matheus Silva, your first step should be $n = 1 + 3(2) - 0 = 7$ by setting $t=0$. So, $(7+2t)-3(2+mt)+mt = 1$ implies $2t(1-m)=0$ and so $m=1$.